# Could not parse callback cache, aborting restore

Tags: ios, flutter

I have created a flutter project. It shows error as "[VERBOSE-1:callback_cache.cc(132)] Could not parse callback cache, aborting restore" while running on Xcode.

Comment: same, did you fix?